# Executing bash script from C++ and read its output ubuntu sdk

Tags: c++, linux, bash, ubuntu, qml

I have a ubuntu application and I'm trying to execute bash scripts from it but it doesn't seem to be working. I tried doing this with system()

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
// tried both
        system("./script.sh");
       // system ("script.sh")

    }
```

Also, i've tried researching this but did not find a solution; is it possible to also read the output and display in textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `popen()`.

```
FILE *script;
char line[LINESIZE];
script = popen("./script.sh", "r");
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), script)) {
    ...
}
pclose(script);
```

It's not relevant that you're running a script. This will work with any shell command.

Comment: It's a standard POSIX function, it doesn't depend on any special library.

Comment: This reads whatever the script writes to its standard output.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to do this in QT, here's what i did:

```
 QProcess proc;

        proc.start("gnome-terminal", QIODevice::ReadWrite);

        if (proc.waitForStarted() == false) {
            qDebug() << "Error starting terminal process";
            qDebug() << proc.errorString();

            return (-1);
        }
```